# Best approach to control access/handle objects/models data passed to View in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, access-control, zend-framework-mvc

I want to pass data to views, and I've two options in my mind (if you know a better approach, please mention).
I am using Zend_Based ORM system, and coded in a way that if I add a new field in database, its automatically available within the model.
1st: I convert the model's data into array and pass the array to the view. This way I will have all the data available within the view, but model's function/operations will not be available. And incase I need specific functionality, i will be coding view helpers while there are chances that the same functionality is already coded within model. e.g. a getting a date in specific format.
2nd: Or I pass the complete model object to the view, this way I will have all the model's functions available, but view will be able to access model's save function which is a bad thing. I can add some more functionality within model to make it read-only, but it will be extra work. 
any suggestions which approach is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the MVC principle it's perfectly fine to [let the View allow access to the Model](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/modelViewController.html). So, pass the complete Model to the View.

By the way, passing arrays around will copy your data (by value), while passing objects around will not (by reference). (Assuming PHP5). Large arrays might affect your performance.

Comment: but if I pass the model, the view will be able to change model's data and even save it into the persistent layer

Comment: If you are concerned with another person editing your templates and 'accidentally' telling your model to save or delete or update, then it's in your best interest to pass only the data you want and not the entire model.  But, as Yeroon stated, it's not "bad" to pass your model object.  This is really just a personal/business rule that you must decide by yourself.

Comment: thanks.<br> or the other option is that before passing the model I drop the mapper and change a flag which will make impossible to attach the mapper again. In this case the object itself will not be able to communicate with the persistent layer, but any linked object will still be able to interact with the persistent layer...